# SonarQube displaying "Simplify this expression"

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, angular5

SonarQube is returning quite a few code smells where I should simplify a single line of code:

```
this.moduleContestViewModel.hasUserParticipated = (accpetedInteraction.length > 0) ? true : false;
```

and

```
const enableCache = (iccid !== undefined) ? false : true;
```

Now this seems as a "simplified" if statement to me already so im not sure what it's expecting. I have created a small function which returns the same thing. Would that work?

This is what I did for the first one:

```
private checkAcceptedInteraction(accpetedInteraction: InteractionGetModel[]): boolean{
    return (accpetedInteraction.length > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Let's think for just a moment - you have an expression you check. That returns `true` or `false` You check the value and if the expression returns `true` you instead reaturn `true`. If the expression returns `false`, you return `false`. So...it's rather useless. `(accpetedInteraction.length > 0) ? true : false;` is just the same as `accpetedInteraction.length > 0`. Which of the two seems simpler to you?

Comment: Uhmm, why didnt I think of that lol. Thanks @VLAZ